# Amstrad CPC 6128 - Key cap spring missing

Tags: keyboards, cpc, amstrad

Of course the unthinkable happened and I lost one cap key spring while cleaning the keyboard. I am still searching but assuming all things went south, what would be the best solution to replace them? Just another keyboard from ebay? Or are there "cheap" solutions?

Are they like similar to other keyboard types?

Comment: Weolcome to Retrocomputing! Did you mix up the digits in the heading?

Comment: If you're in the UK or willing to pay for postage from there then eBay offers a potential solution: https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Amstrad-CPC-464-Key-Spring-Set/283958550115?hash=item421d3f9e63:g:rIAAAOSwAG9fG98P ; this is too ephemeral an answer to be an actual answer though. Hopefully somebody will know exactly which standard spring to buy?

Comment: I actually found a guy in Romania on ebay I think, who also sells individual keys (3EUR per key + 3 EUR untracked delivery). Gave it a try with this. Didn't find anything where i just could find the springs

Answer (score 2):

In the worst of the cases, in which you had really lost it you could try the following options which do not require buying specialized springs:

1. Scavenge springs from broken/unusable equipment. Pens can be a good source of them, especially when their ink has been depleted.
2. Make your own. You only need some wire, basic tools and tenacity to make new springs suitable to your specific needs.